# Laplace transform of the following: $f(t)=\int\limits_{0}^{t} \frac{\cosh (\tau) - 1}{\tau} d\tau$

Tags: laplace-transform

I thought it would be a simple one, however, that integral of $f(t)$ cannot be expressed in terms of standard functions...and I'm pretty much confused.

What should I do?

Comment: What are the relations between the Laplace transforms of $g$ and of $g'$? What are the relations between the Laplace transforms of $t\mapsto g(t)$ and of $t\mapsto t\cdot g(t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$L(\cosh t-1)=\frac{s}{s^2-1}-\frac{1}{s}$$ so  $$L(\frac{\cosh t-1}{t})=\int_{s}^{\infty}(\frac{u}{u^2-1}-\frac{1}{u})du$$ and $$Lf(t)=\frac{1}{s}\int_{s}^{\infty}(\frac{u}{u^2-1}-\frac{1}{u})du=\frac{1}{s}\left[Ln\frac{\sqrt{u^2-1}}{u}\right]_{s}^{\infty}=\frac{1}{s}Ln\frac{s}{\sqrt{s^2-1}}$$

Comment: It's $cosh(t)$, not $cos(t)$...

Comment: @Dear Lebesgue, thanks

Comment: Is that the answer or should I integrate the last line of your answer?

Comment: @ You should calculate the integrals

Comment: @ِDear Lebesgue,it's the same answer that you want

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\tilde{\fermi}\pars{s}}\equiv\int_{0}^{\infty}\fermi\pars{t}\expo{-st}\,\dd t
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-st}\int_{0}^{t}{\cosh\pars{\tau} - 1 \over \tau}
\,\dd\tau\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\cosh\pars{\tau} - 1 \over \tau}\int_{\tau}^{\infty}\expo{-st}\,\dd t\,\dd\tau
={1 \over s}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\cosh\pars{\tau} - 1 \over \tau}\expo{-s\tau}\,\dd\tau
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 2s}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\expo{\pars{1 - s}\tau} + \expo{-\pars{1 + s}\tau} -  2\expo{-s\tau} \over \tau}\,\dd\tau
\\[5mm]&=-\,{1 \over 2s}\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{\tau}\bracks{%
{\expo{\pars{1 - s}\tau}\pars{1 - s}
-\expo{-\pars{1 + s}\tau}\pars{1 + s}} + 2\expo{-s\tau}s}\,\dd\tau
\\[5mm]&=-\,{1 \over 2s}\,\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}\partiald{}{\mu}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{-\tau^{\mu}\expo{-\pars{s - 1}\tau}\pars{s - 1}
-\tau^{\mu}\expo{-\pars{s + 1}\tau}\pars{s + 1}
+2\tau^{\mu}\expo{-s\tau}s}\,\dd\tau
\\[5mm]&=-\,{1 \over 2s}\,\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{%
-\,{1 \over \pars{s - 1}^{\mu}} - {1 \over \pars{s + 1}^{\mu}}
+{2 \over s^{\mu}}}\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large
-\,{1 \over 2s}\,\ln\pars{1 - {1 \over s^{2}}}}
\end{align}